# What does the arrow in the bottom left corner do?

Tags: draw-something

When watching someone's drawing bring drawn, in the bottom of the drawing area (above the letters) there are two icons.

I know the one on the right, which looks like two arrows around each other, shuffles the letters around.

What does the one on the left do? It looks like a curved arrow pointing to the right, but I've not been able to notice any function. I thought it might be to redraw the opponent's drawing, or to skip to the final result, but it never seems to do anything when I press it, either while the drawing is in progress or when it's finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That arrow recalls all the letters that you've put down so far. So try guessing incorrectly, then pressing the button; all the letters will recall to the letter cache.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't notice that before...I'm going to go ahead and say it's because *my first guess is always correct.*